# Structure error: Not recognized even though it is included

Tags: c++

More quetions:
i get an unrecognized 'eld' from mai structure.

header contains:

```
const int c=10;
struct Array
{
int n;
int els[c];
 };
```

The error i get is:

> error: request for member 'els' in 'A', which is of non-class type 'Array [(((unsigned int)(((int)a) + -0x000000001)) + 1)] {aka Array [(((unsigned int)(((int)a) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]}'

Code:

```
Array arrayInp()
/* Create 2 vectors by the length defined by the user*/
{
int a,b,i;

cout<<"enter length of the first array: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter length of the second array: ";
cin>>b;

Array A[a],B[b];

cout<<"insert first array:";
for (int i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    cin>>A.els[i];
}


cout<<"insert second array:";
for (int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        cin>>B.els[i];
    }
return A,B;
}
```

One more error, my return isent right can someone explain me a way how to return the array structures from the functions?
after build errors:

> ..\scr\main.cpp:32:10: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>   ..\scr\main.cpp:32:10: error: could not convert '(0, ((Array*)(& B)))' from 'Array*' to 'Array'
>   ..\scr\main.cpp:11:10: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
>   ..\scr\main.cpp:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: It is unclear, to me at least, what the code is trying to achieve. The number of iterations of the `for` loops would not populate all elements of `els` for each element in the array `A` (or `B`). Is it not the `els` member that should be dynamic (size supplied by user)? Is there a reason STL is not being used (e.g. `std::vector<int>`).

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
Array A[a]
```

defines an array of `Array` called `A`. You need to index `A` to access the members of `Array` or (I suspect this was your intention) change declarations to:

```
Array A, B;
```

*Just to point out that variable length arrays are not standard C++ (I think they are a GCC extension).*

The `return` statement:

```
return A,B;
```

is using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). In this case `B` will returned and is the cause of `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect`.

The `unused variable i` warning is complaining that the `i` declared at the beginning of the function `int a, b. i;` is unused, this is due to redeclaration of `i` in both `for` loops: either remove the `i` from top declaration or don't redeclare in `for` loops.

Without seeing the full source code, I suspect the `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` is because there is no `return 0;` in `int main()`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `A[i].els`, not `A.els[i]`.

Comment: I did the changes you suggested, still same error:
..\scr\main.cpp:32:10: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
..\scr\main.cpp:32:10: error: could not convert '(0, ((Array*)(& B)))' from 'Array*' to 'Array'
..\scr\main.cpp:11:10: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
..\scr\main.cpp:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: @BogdanMaier: `return A,B;` is equivalent to `return B;`.

Comment: You say "still same error", but that's clearly a completely different error. The reason you're now seeing a new error is that there were in fact multiple things wrong with your original code.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to hmjd comment, I think I should point out that this has already been implemented but better by the standard library; it is almost always better to use std library constructs where possible because they are well know to other C++ developers, their functionality is well documented and finally they have a uniform interface which integrates with other standard features (such as standard algorithms).

There are two construct you can use

The fixed size:

```
std::array<int, 6> array_; //an array of six elements
```

And the resizable

```
std::vector<int> vector_(6); //a container of six elements.
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: oh, thanks, but the thing is i need to use my construction.... that's the requirement.

Comment: of the problem i have for school.

Comment: if i would have known i would have not ask... if you can help em fin if not don't worry i wont be mad or anything... but don't start holding me lesson about anything >.>